# Transferring OS from one medium to another

Tags: partition, dd, manjaro, bootable, file-transfer

I have a USB drive with Manjaro ARM on it (which is used for Raspberry Pi 4 system) and an empty SD card.
Is there a possible way to transfer the OS from USB drive to SD card, while preserving the partitions?
If it is possible, can it be done while Manjaro is running?

Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk # partitions on USB Drive
sda      8:0    1  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1 213.6M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    1  14.7G  0 part /
zram0  254:0    0  11.2G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

Comment: What is the device path of the sd card when connected? /dev/sdb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there a possible way to transfer the OS from USB drive to SD card, while preserving the partitions?

Yes, assuming the sd card it as least as big as the usb drive. You can run `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda` to get the size of your usb drive in bytes, and by changing the device path to the sd card you can ensure it is at least as many bytes.

It is perhaps not very likely that the devices are exactly the same size, so I would preferrably create an identical partition table (with same partition numbers for minimum hassle) manually on the sd card. This ensures that the extra disk space potentially available on the sd card can later be used for e.g. extending the root partition or creating new partitions. Use `sfdisk -l /dev/sda` to get a list of partitions on /dev/sda in units of sectors, and then use `fdisk /dev/sdb` to create the same partitions on the sd card (assuming your sd card device is /dev/sdb, please update as necessary).

After recreating the partitions you can copy the contents of each partition one at a time.

> 2. If it is possible, can it be done while Manjaro is running?

Yes, but in that case you should mount the filesystems read only to avoid the risk of the operating system corrupting the copy should it write anything to the disk while you are copying.

Here are the commands to do just that and to copy the two partitions you listed in your question, assuming you have created the partitions as described above, and again assuming your sd card is /dev/sdb:

```bsh
mount /dev/sda1 -oremount,ro
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1048576
mount /dev/sda2 -oremount,rw

mount /dev/sda2 -oremount,ro
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb2 bs=1048576
mount /dev/sda2 -oremount,rw
```

Possibly some software might not like that the root filesystem is temporarily mounted read-only; a reboot will fix that.

Comment: The sd card I use is 64GB and the USB drive is 16GB? Does the difference in size incur some complication?

Comment: No, just follow the instructions :)